# WPF Template Recommendation Free

Tags: gratis, gui, wpf

So I am a student and I work in an environment where only the result matters, meaning, nobody cares if I use the best coding practices, MVVM, or the likes. They are researchers and need an app that, *just works*!

It so happens that many come from non-technical background, meaning from Archeology to Zoology, I cater to everybody. The **only** thing common between them is that all hate CLI apps and need GUI apps that run nicely on their Full HD or 4k screens.

I am C# developer and the UI tool of my choice is WPF.
To create nice looking apps I generally use Microsoft's Ribbon Framework. A typical app made by me looks like this:

[image: Sample App]

The ribbon looks great as it is pre-styled with nice effects, scales well and so on.

However, now it so happens as more and more of my researchers upgrade to Windows 8 and 10 these apps are starting to look bad and well simply doesn't look nicer any more. They also want the standard `toolbar`, `menubar` kind of design, something like this (I did not make it but I really like the simple design!):

[image]

So my question, is there any `sample app`, `template`, `put_buzzword_here`, that actually has a simple standard start UI like this which I can edit to fit my needs (with MVVM or whatever, as I said I don't care), so that I don't have to design everything from scratch and skin them (I am really bad at styling WPF apps!)?

**Note:** I tried contacting *Telerik*, *AppDev* etc, for academic pricing. They were too costly. Telerik didn't even care to reply. While Visual Studio is free for us, I really can't afford a $400 for some controls. I tried *SyncFusion*, it makes my setup very slow.

Thanks.

Comment: So basically you're looking for an alternative to WPF (WPF, to my understanding, a C# template UI) that has the Windows 10 modern look to it and doesn't cost all that much to use for commercial use?

Comment: @Tom No, not an alternative but rather some free, well designed templates, starter sample apps for WPF. I cannot switch from C# as a lot of our legacy code is in C# and needs nightly changes.

Comment: ok, I see, I've added the gratis tag

Comment: The only one I've found (please forgive me if this is way off, I haven't exactly every used WPF or created anything in it) is called [Modern UI for WPF (MUI)](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui) - [here are some screenshots](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/wiki/Screenshots). Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks. yes, very similar. But as you see its Modern UI, Windows 10 ish, I want Windows 7 ish UI template.

Comment: @jeet: Could you please provide some details about what makes your setup slow when using Syncfusion? Thanks.

Comment: @DavisJebaraj The toolbox takes ages to load on VS 2015, at least in my case.

Comment: @jeet Ok. We will look into this - we will also put together a simple sample and post here.

Comment: @DavisJebaraj Sure, thanks! Also does SyncFusion actually allow to create out of the box Windows like this, ?

Comment: @jeet We have a Skin manager that provide built in styling. We don't have preconfigured templates, but the idea has been considered before and we are open to implementing. We will start with a sample and go from there.

Comment: you might be looking for something like this: [http://mahapps.com/](http://mahapps.com/) If you want to use Google's material desing with it, you can use [this package](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/MahApps.Metro-integration).

Comment: "these apps are starting to look bad and well simply doesn't look nicer any more" - could you please specify this extremely vague problem description a bit, to help future visitors evaluate whether they are facing the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Essential Studio for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf) includes a [Skin/Theme manager](http://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/themes/getting-started) with built in support for several themes.

While we don't have the concept of application templates, we have the controls required to create most common application templates. We have created a [sample application](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/158104/ze/Sample1732781833.zip).

[image: WPF UI]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! No company would do that! You guys are awesome compared to Telerik and the lot!

Comment: @jeet Thanks for the kind words. Please feel free to contact us through the Syncfusion [support system](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac) if you have any usage questions or post in Stack overflow.